# Restore jenkins root folder config.xml file

Tags: java, jenkins, devops, winscp

I accidentally deleted config.xml under jenkins root folder. Still jenkins is running. I hope it will fail once restart happens. Can any one help me to get config.xml of root folder from GUI.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you open manage Jenkins -> Configure system and still see the configurations under it? If yes can you save them and notice if the config.xml gets regenerated?

Comment: @RavindranathBarathy you saved my job. yes config.xml got generated with new values..is that the same old file?

Comment: should be the same!

Comment: Thanks for your help..reply to the question i can mark it as answer.

Comment: Added below. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and observe if you still have all your configurations in it(in GUI). If yes, go ahead and save it. This should most likely regenerate the config.xml.

Once that's done. Go ahead and look in the config.xml file to see if your jobs, ldap configurations are available there.

Going forward use the [ThinBackup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/thinBackup) to backup your configurations in the future. Its also always recommended to take backup of your `Jenkins_Home` directory. Use the [Job Config history plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) to track and revert changes that is done to each job and global configurations.